# Resolving Mass-loading problems in WebSphere Commerce Instance creation

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-commerce, wcs

I am trying to create an instance using the Configuration Manager of WCS 7. I am working on a Win 7 x64 machine with DB2 9.5 64 bit version.

I am struck with this Massloading error when the instance creation happens :

In createInstanceANT.log file :

> [Massload] Massloading
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\CommerceServer\schema\xml\wcs.keys.xml Error in
>   MassLoading, please check logs for details.

The error log shows the following error :

> [jcc][10165][10044][4.3.111] **Invalid database URL syntax:
>   jdbc:db2://:0/WCSDEMO. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815**
>   C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\COMMER~2\config\DEPLOY~1\xml\createBaseSchema.xml:185:
>   Error in massloading

WCSDEMO is the database name. The Massloader is not able to get the URL and port to connect. It is supposedly getting them from createInstance.properties file but it is not working. The createInstance.properties file has all the details of the DB to connect.

What could be the reason for this error and how to resolve it ? Is there any configuration change that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more details.

look inside the messages.txt file located in WC_install_dir/instances/instance_name/logs
and confirm what the exact issue is. If it is related to jdbc driver being wrong I may be able to help you.

Comment: The messages.txt is not showing any new error. It is getting arguments (schema,user,pwd,dbname etc)from createInstance.properties and it is getting a new database connection and then it is showing the "Invalid database URL syntax" error. I dont think it is any jdbc error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into massloading problems with external systems. Eg. databases not on the same machine as the WAS installation.

In these cases I look for the

As you can see setting the loaderDBName to just the name of the database would look on the local machine. But by changing this statement so you load with the syntax

loaderDBName=[DATABASE_SERVER_NAME]:[PORT]/[DATABASE_NAME]

You'll be able to massload using the commerce standard scripts. These changes needs to be done in many scripts. Both for updating fixpacks and enabling features. If you run database updates without the changes it will crash at first and have done all the schema changes to the database that you then need to comment out before trying again.

Answer (score -1):

IBM Software Support is your friend.  They'll help you fix it.